# How can i use try/catch to solve Axios error in my code using React Js

Tags: reactjs

How can I solve the Axios Error in my code using the try/catch method . Am building a chat application with react js and stream API, when I try to signup using my signup form I get the Axios error which I don't know how I can debug it. You can help me out by editing my attached code so that i can continue with my project. Thanks in advance.

```
// below is my code//

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import axios from 'axios';

import signinImage from '../assets/signup.jpg';

const cookies = new Cookies();

const initialState = {
    fullName: '',
    username: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    avatarURL: '',
}

const Auth = () => {
    const [form, setForm] = useState(initialState);
    const [isSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(true);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setForm({ ...form, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { username, password, phoneNumber, avatarURL } = form;

        const URL = 'https://localhost:5000/auth';
        // const URL = 'https://medical-pager.herokuapp.com/auth';

        const { data: { token, userId, hashedPassword, fullName } } = await axios.post(`${URL}/${isSignup ? 'signup' : 'login'}`, {
            username, password, fullName: form.fullName, phoneNumber, avatarURL,
        });

        cookies.set('token', token);
        cookies.set('username', username);
        cookies.set('fullName', fullName);
        cookies.set('userId', userId);

        if(isSignup) {
            cookies.set('phoneNumber', phoneNumber);
            cookies.set('avatarURL', avatarURL);
            cookies.set('hashedPassword', hashedPassword);
        }

        window.location.reload();
    }

    const switchMode = () => {
        setIsSignup((prevIsSignup) => !prevIsSignup);
    }

    return (
        <div className="auth__form-container">
            <div className="auth__form-container_fields">
                <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content">
                    <p>{isSignup ? 'Sign Up' : 'Sign In'}</p>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        {isSignup && (
                            <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_input">
                                <label htmlFor="fullName">Full Name</label>
                                <input 
                                    name="fullName" 
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Full Name"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}
                        <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_input">
                            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                                <input 
                                    name="username" 
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Username"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        {isSignup && (
                            <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_input">
                                <label htmlFor="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                                <input 
                                    name="phoneNumber" 
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Phone Number"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}
                        {isSignup && (
                            <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_input">
                                <label htmlFor="avatarURL">Avatar URL</label>
                                <input 
                                    name="avatarURL" 
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Avatar URL"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}
                        <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_input">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input 
                                    name="password" 
                                    type="password"
                                    placeholder="Password"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                        {isSignup && (
                            <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_input">
                                <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                                <input 
                                    name="confirmPassword" 
                                    type="password"
                                    placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                            )}
                        <div className="auth__form-container_fields-content_button">
                            <button>{isSignup ? "Sign Up" : "Sign In"}</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div className="auth__form-container_fields-account">
                        <p>
                            {isSignup
                             ? "Already have an account?" 
                             : "Don't have an account?"
                             }
                             <span onClick={switchMode}>
                             {isSignup ? 'Sign In' : 'Sign Up'}
                             </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div className="auth__form-container_image">
                <img src={signinImage} alt="sign in" />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Auth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const { username, password, phoneNumber, avatarURL } = form;

      const URL = 'https://localhost:5000/auth';
      // const URL = 'https://medical-pager.herokuapp.com/auth';

      const { data: { token, userId, hashedPassword, fullName } } = await axios.post(`${URL}/${isSignup ? 'signup' : 'login'}`, {
          username, password, fullName: form.fullName, phoneNumber, avatarURL,
      });

      cookies.set('token', token);
      cookies.set('username', username);
      cookies.set('fullName', fullName);
      cookies.set('userId', userId);

      if(isSignup) {
          cookies.set('phoneNumber', phoneNumber);
          cookies.set('avatarURL', avatarURL);
          cookies.set('hashedPassword', hashedPassword);
      }

      window.location.reload();
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
}
```